# How to position rangeSelector buttons to the right Highstock/Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I cannot seem to find a way of how to position all the buttons to the right. They are positioned on the left side by default. I have buttons for 1 day | 1 week | 2 weeks | 1 month but I need them to be on the top right side of the chart/page

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaltey this option is not available, but you can vote for it [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)

In the next relase (nowadays beta) you will have chance to use buttonPosition.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fn90bye0/5/

```
buttonPosition: {
        x: 110,
        y: 117
},
```

Comment: More specifically, here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2436599-add-ability-to-change-rangeselector-position

Comment: Cool, but how do I keep them always to the right? Even if I resize the page?

Comment: Prepare function and return value, based on the contianer width. You need to develop it on your own.